# Using the definition of Convergence to Prove whether a sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Use the formal definition of the limit of a sequence to prove the following convergence: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n^{1/3}}=0$$

I know that a sequence $\{ a_n \}$ converges to a real number $L\in \mathbb{R}$ if, for every positive number $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such whenever $n≥N$ it follows that $|a_n-L|< \epsilon$.

I don't understand how to exactly find an epsilon that works for this sequence, though.

Comment: Please use Mathjax

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$
|\frac{\sin n^2}{n^{1/3}}|\leq |\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}| 
$$
Which simplifies our problem. Then you want to find some $N(\epsilon)$ for some fixed $\epsilon$, so we need
$$
|\frac{1}{N(\epsilon)^{1/3}}|<\epsilon\Rightarrow \frac{1}{N(\epsilon)^{1/3}}<\epsilon\\
\Rightarrow N(\epsilon)>\epsilon^{-3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Our sequence is $\dfrac{\sin (n^2)}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$.

Now, what we are going to do first, is the following:

note that $\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{n}} \leq \dfrac{\sin (n^2)}{\sqrt[3]{n}}  \leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$.  Rewritten succinctly, $\Bigg|\dfrac{\sin (n^2)}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\Bigg| \leq  \Bigg|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\Bigg|$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Now, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N \implies \Bigg|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\Bigg| < \epsilon$. Namely, we can let $N = \dfrac{1}{\epsilon^3}$, for example.
Therefore,
$$
n > N \implies \Bigg|\dfrac{\sin (n^2)}{\sqrt[3]{n}}-0\Bigg| \leq  \Bigg|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\Bigg| < \epsilon
$$

Hence, we are done, with $a=0$.

What was important in this proof, was the use of the boundedness of the $\sin$ function. It allowed us to considerably simplify the calculation of $N$ given $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, @qbert. Do not worry if I raced you to it, your answer may offer more insight to the questioner. I will up vote it if it comes. There it comes, and there comes the $+1$.